# Primeng Datatable 4.3: Cell editor content missed

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

**I'm using primeng 4.3**

I've coded this primeng datatable:

```
<form>
  <p-dataTable [value]="quotes | async" [editable]="true">
    <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" 
      [header]="col.header" [editable]="col.editable">
      <ng-template let-col let-quote="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
        <p-spinner size="30" [(ngModel)]="quote[col.field]" name="quote"></p-spinner>
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
  </p-dataTable>
</form>
```

As you can see, I'm using an spinner editor in order to edit each cell value:

[image]

The problem appears when I want to edit whichever cell:

[image]

As you can see the content is gone.

You can take a look on this [**Stackblitz project**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-nh8vry).

Any ideas?

Comment: What is quote in [(ngModel)]="quote[col.field]"? is it should be quotes instead of quote?

Comment: Take a look on `let-quote="rowData"`...

Answer (score 1):

This should in fact work fine if you didn't have the typos. Ex: `[field]="col.field`, and not closing `<p-spinner>` correctly

Corrected code:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="quotes | async" [editable]="true">
  <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field"
    [header]="col.header" [editable]="true">
    <ng-template let-col let-quote="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
      <p-spinner size="30" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                           [(ngModel)]="quote[col.field]"
                           name="quote">
      </p-spinner>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Maybe the incorrect code was only a typo here on Stackoverflow.

Either way, here is the working
[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-ur8sgu?file=app/app.component.html) solution so you can see it in action.

Comment: Sorry, It was a miswriting. I missed to comment that this `p-dataTable` is enclosed inside a form. It keeps failing... If tested a bit on yout shared stackblitz project. If you enclose the datatable inside a form, you can see a similar behavior...

Comment: @Jordi, edit the question and add the Stackblitz example (non working)

Comment: The edit you did is for your local environment only. Do a fork of the stackblitz, then do an edit and share a new link

Comment: [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-nh8vry) you have the project.

Comment: If your table isn't related to a form then why do you wrap it within the form?

Comment: The project I'm working is a bit more complex. I've only exposed a minimal example.  Currently, it's enclosed inside a form where other fields have some validation constraints. However, since this dataTable has no validation rules, I could move it out of form. But, my question now  would be, what about if I would need to add some validation rules on each cell value?

Comment: Well, if you want to keep it wrapped within the form, you can use `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` on `<p-spinner>`. I edited the answer